# Trigger find action in monaco without find panel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, monaco-editor

I am adding a find functionality where the user clicks on a particular word and the Monaco editor lists all its occurrences, I want to trigger find action programmatically but without opening the find panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this would help:

```
editor.trigger('Highlight matches', 'editor.action.selectHighlights')
const selections = editor.getSelections();
```

Now you have [`Selection`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/classes/monaco.selection.html) objects for all occurrences of that word.

Comment: I had to do a lot of stuff to make it work , but yeah this is a good approach , I used color highlights.